# Group a list of objects by Unique key as a object using Java API

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream, java

I am trying to create a key and value relationship and return in a json format between list of data returned by Database. I'm able to achieve the relationship  but not able to get the desired Json Format as a output

```
StudentProfResponse = profRepository.getstudentProfessorHirarchy();

studentprofResponse.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentProfResponse::getProfessorName));
```

> Db Results

**ProfessorName ProfessorId StudentId StudentName**

Vinay    P123      S567   Karthik
   Vinay  P123   S568   Jeevan
   Mayank P657   S569   Meena
   Vasu   P723   S570   Vijay

> Json Format Im getting with the above code

```
[
{
    "vinay": [
        {
            "studentId": "S567",
            "StudentName": "Karthik",
            "professorName": "Vinay",
            "professorId": "P123"
        },
        {
            "studentId": "S568",
            "StudentName": "Jeevan",
            "professorName": "Vinay",
            "professorId": "P123"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Mayank": [
        {
            "studentId": "S569",
            "StudentName": "Meena",
            "professorName": "Mayank",
            "professorId": "P657"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "vasu": [
        {
            "studentId": "S570",
            "StudentName": "Vijay",
            "professorName": "Vasu",
            "professorId": "P723"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

> Json format im Expecting

```
[
 {
    "professorName": "Vinay",
    "professorId" : "P123",
    "studentDetails": [
        {
            "studentId": "S567",
            "StudentName": "Karthik"
        },
        {
            "studentId": "S568",
            "StudentName": "Jeevan"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "professorName": "Mayank",
    "professorId" : "P657",
    "studentDetails": [
        {
            "studentId": "S569",
            "StudentName": "Meena"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "professorName": "Vasu",
    "professorId" : "P723",
    "studentDetails": [
        {
            "studentId": "S570",
            "StudentName": "Vijay"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

Is there a way, I can achieve above Json Format through Java 8 stream API by creating a bean class like and send a List of studprofrelationship details

```
public class StudentProfessorRelationship {

private Integer professorNo;

private String professorName;

private List<StudentDetails> studentDetails;

}
```

Comment: Could you provider code for the class StudentProfResponse ? Why you absolutely Need streams ? You can do that with old vanilla Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Collectors.toMap with mergeFunction parameter of [Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
  studentprofResponse.stream()
    .map(resp-> new StudentProfessorRelationship(/*add arguments*/) )
    .collect(
             Collectors.toMap( 
                              StudentProfessorRelationship::getProfessorName, 
                              Function.identity(),
                              (relationship1, relationship2) -> {  
                                      relationship1.getstudentDetails().addAll(
                                           relationship2.getstudentDetails()); 
                                       return realtionship1;} ))  
      .values();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sourav, It's Working. U should keep  relationship1.getstudentDetails() instead of relationship

Comment: is there anyway if i want to accommodate list of courses for each student in studentdetails class in the same solution u have provided ?